# How to translate “this”, used for an unknown thing when mentioned the first time?

Tags: english-to-german, determiners

The word *this* has a couple of meanings in English. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/this) states 5.
I am specifically interested in the translation of the fourth meaning:

> A known (thing) (used in first mentioning a person or thing that the speaker does not think is known to the audience). Compare with “a certain …”
>
> > I met this woman the other day who’s allergic to wheat. I didn’t even know that was possible!
> >
> > There’s just this nervous mannerism that Bob has with his hands, and it drives me crazy.

This description led me to *certain*, which translates to *bestimmt*. Is it safe to say, that “Ich traf diese bestimmte Frau” means “I met this woman”? I am worried it does not.

I actually need this because I don’t know how to say the following:

> In my country there is this tradition …
>
> In meinem Heimatland gibt es diese bestimmte Tradition …

Is this correct?

Comment: Man kann beobachten, dass 'bestimmt' sehr oft als reines Füllwort verwendet wird, ähnlich wie 'natürlich', und genau das Gegenteil der Fall ist, nämlich Unbestimmtheit. Stilistisch dürfte 'there is this tradition' auf Englisch ähnlich schwach sein (gegenüber 'there is a tradition ...') wie im Deutschen, imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of three possibilities: *diese eine* (*this single one*), *jene* (*that*) and — as mentioned in a comment — *(so) eine* (~*such a*).

Take the first one if you think that the thing you refer to is unknown and possibly quite unique.

> Und dann traf ich diese eine Frau, die allergisch auf Weizen reagiert. Ich wusste gar nicht, dass es sowas gibt.

Take the second one if you talk about something/someone where you think that everyone can think of something/someone else they know and have a vivid idea in their mind.

> Bob hat jene nervöse Eigenart mit den Händen rumzufuchteln, die einen einfach in den Wahnsinn treibt.

Take the third one if you talk about something/someone where it’s possibly unknown but not necessarily unique.

> In meinem Heimatland gibt es (so) eine Tradition, …

Answer (score 7):

No need to make things so complicated. German has exactly the same paradoxical use of *this/diese*, so literal translations will do.
The only thing that’s tricky is translating “there’s just” in the third sentence, but this has nothing to do with the demonstratives involved:

> Ich traf neulich *diese* Frau, die allergisch gegen Weizen ist. Ich wusste nicht einmal, dass das möglich ist!
>
> Bob hat einfach *diese* nervöse Angewohnheit mit seinen Händen, und das macht mich wahnsinnig.
>
> In meinem Land gibt es *diese* Tradition, … [better: bei mir zu Hause, in meiner Heimat, in meinem Heimatland]

I have consciously let pass a few opportunities to make the translation better by using differently constructed German idioms, but again this has nothing to do with this particular use of demonstratives.

Answer (score -2):

You could use

> Ich hab neulich diese Frau getroffen (weitere Erklärung).

For example:

> Ich habe neulich diese Frau getroffen, von der ich Dir schon erzählt habe.

or

> Ich habe gerade diese Frau gesehen, die ich mich nicht traue, anzusprechen.

Or for your second phrase:

> Wir haben da diese Tradition (weitere Erklärung).

For example:

> Wir haben da diese Tradition, dass man jemanden, der unter einem Mistelzweig steht, küssen muss.

Comment: You _could_ say so, but no native speaker _would_ say it (except when translating and being too close to the English original). Depending on context, _ein_ would be used or _so ein_.

Comment: Thank you both very much. chirlu, would you mind writing an example?

Comment: @chirlu if you google "neulich diese Frau", you will quickly see that you are wrong.

Comment: I googled this and I fail to see where he is wrong. Please explain.
Actually, it's the opposite. The sites that show up contain the phrase "Ich habe neulich eine Frau getroffen..."

Comment: @user244609 use hyphens. you will find plenty examples where you get the exact phrase "[ich habe] neulich diese Frau [getroffen]" when you search for "neulich diese Frau" (hyphens included). So he is obviously wrong in stating that noone would use this.

Comment: @Burki: The statement may well have been a bit too strong, but the first few results (with “quotation marks” – not hy-phen-s) don’t disprove it. They either include a photograph that _dieser_ refers to, are translations, or by non-native speakers. But today, everything is being said. ;-)

Comment: @chirlu thank you for the correction about the quotation marks. My answer clearly states that further explanation, which particular woman or tradition is meant should follow after that (since i understand the original question as to imply that this will follow)

Comment: Wir haben im Deutschen sowas wie Großschreibung. ;) — Bzgl. den Beispielsätzen: Das dritte Beispiel ist absolut in Ordnung und richtig, auch wenn es natürlich dazu Alternativen gibt (die von chirlu genannt wurden). Beim ersten ist es auch richtig, nur nicht die gängigste Variante. "die Frau", "die eine Frau" oder "jene Frau" sind wahrscheinlicher. Beim zweiten ist der Satz Kontext etwas merkwürdig. Es suggeriert, dass es nur "eine Frau", die du dich nicht traust anzusprechen. Gibt es wirklich nur eine? Also das Beispiel ist etwas holprig und es schwer zu sagen, ob "diese" dort richtig wäre.

Comment: @ Em1 Naja... ich finde "diese eine Frau, die allergisch auf Weizen reagiert" jetzt auch nicht viel besser ;-) und "jene" in gesprochener Sprache würden wahrscheinlich die meisten Muttersprachler als sehr gestelzt empfinden. Aber danke für die Edits, und ja, ich soltle da sorgfältiger sein. Sorry @community.

Comment: @Burki Wohlbemerkt widerspreche ich nicht deiner Grundaussage. "Diese" ist sehr wohl richtig. Sieht man auch, weil eine andere Antwort, die sich auf "diese" fokussiert, schon 4 Upvotes hat. Die beiden Downvoter sollten wohl auch die Antwort von HansAdler downvoten, wenn sie denn konsequent wären. Das Manko deiner Antwort sind nur die Beispiele und eine fehlende Erklärung, weswegen ich hier kein Upvote vergeben habe.